# The plugin generated 225 characters of unexpected output during activation

Tags: php, plugin-development, mysql

I am getting the famous *"The plugin generated xxx characters of unexpected output during activation."* error when I activate plugin I am working on.

Terminal says my files are in **us-ascii**, but when I am working on this files in my PHP Storm, there is **UTF-8** mark displayed in the bottom right corner.

I think I don't have empty spaces because my PHP Storm removes them automatically on command+s.

I tried:

- With and without: ?>
- With and without $table_name dynamic prefix declaration
- With and without `$tbyb_db_version` (version) declaration
- With both `add_option` and `update_option` for `add_option( 'tbyb_db_version', self::$tbyb_db_version );` line
- With both procedural and OOP static function defining

This is my `class.TbybInstall.php` class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Prevent intruders from sneaking around
 */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );


/**
 * TbybInstall class
 */
if ( !class_exists( 'TbybInstall' ) ) {
    class TbybInstall
    {

        public static $tbyb_db_version = '1.0';

        public static function create_tbyb_prepared_carts_table() {

            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tbyb_prepared_carts';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  product_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  variation_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  imported_to_cart tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  ordered tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  quantity int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
            dbDelta( $sql );

            add_option( 'tbyb_db_version', self::$tbyb_db_version );
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `plugin-name.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:     Plugin name
 * Plugin URI:      plugin-uri
 * Description:     Description
 * Version:         1.0.0
 * Author:          Tahi reu
 * Author URI:      github-link
 * License:         GPL
 * License URI:     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php
 */


/*
 * Prevent intruders from sneaking around
 */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );



/*
 * Current plugin version - https://semver.org
 * This should be updated as new versions are released
 */
define( 'PLUGIN_NAME', '1.0.0' );



/*
 * Variables
 * */
const TEXT_DOMAIN = "plugin-name";



/*
 * Load functions
 */
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'functions.php';



/*
 * Load classes
 */
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class.PreparedCarts.php';
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class.ReturnOptions.php';



/*
 * Check if WooCommerce is installed and active
 */
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ) {


    /* Create database table on plugin install */
    function create_tables(){

        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class.TbybInstall.php';
        TbybInstall::create_tbyb_prepared_carts_table();

    }

    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'TbybInstall', 'create_tables' ) );


    /* Do the work */
    PreparedCarts::on_load();
    ReturnOptions::on_load();


} else {

    /* Abort and display info message */
    PreparedCarts::abort();

}
```

Any help/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "unexpected output" is probably a fatal error message. Check your error logs.

Comment: I see 2 spaces before the opening `<?php` in your `class.TbybInstall.php` file -- are they present on the server, or are they a copy-and-paste artifact present only here?

Comment: I don't have anything related to this in my debug.log file. Those two spaces somehow occurred when I pasted code here (I fixed that now). There is no any empty space before <?php in my .php file.

Comment: Check your Apache (or whatever webserver you're using) error logs as well as `debug.log`.

Comment: Seems like there is no any recent errors in /var/log/apache2/error_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. Problem was in way I was using `register_activation_hook`.

I loaded `TbybInstall` along with other classes:

```
/*
 * Load classes
 */
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class.PreparedCarts.php';
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class.ReturnOptions.php';
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class.TbybInstall.php';
```

...and I used `register_activation_hook` in a way which is more similar to [official WordPress guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins):

```
/* Create database table on plugin install */
function create_tables(){
    TbybInstall::create_tbyb_prepared_carts_table();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_tables' );
```

And that's it.